# In wxpython, how to select a particular text and set its font style selected

Tags: wxpython

I've created a text editor in wxpython but I can't get the selected text.
I guess I'm using the function GetSelectedString() function wrong

def OnSelectFont(self,e):

```
    dialog = wx.FontDialog(None, wx.FontData())
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        data=dialog.GetFontData()

        self.text.GetSelectedString.SetFont(font)

    dialog.Destroy()
```

Comment: What control are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `wx.TextCtrl` of style `wx.TE_RICH` as in:

`self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.button, style=wx.TE_RICH)`

Then, for instance for setting the selection bold, you would do:

```
    font = wx.Font(10, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, False)
    style = self.text.GetDefaultStyle()
    style.SetFont(font)
    (begin, end) = self.text.GetSelection()
    self.text.SetStyle(begin, end, style)
```

Having `wx.TE_RICH` is crucial here, as otherwise you wouldn't be able to `SetStyle`.